# two weeks out of / (away from) / off the surgery

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know which of the following is correct, and if all are, what the difference is.

> John is two weeks **out of** / **from** / **away from** / **off** the surgery.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

> out of

This use sounds ok, but means that it has been two weeks since the surgery ended. However "the" would have to be deleted for it to sound more natural. A more common way this is said is "John has been out of surgery for two weeks"

> from

This makes sense and would mean that after two more weeks, John will have the surgery

> away from

See "from"

> off

This doesn't really make sense. When I hear "John is two weeks off ... ", my mind wants to fill it in with a vice like smoking, alcohol, drugs or with medication.

Being "two weeks off cigarettes" means this person made a concision or forced effort to quit their habit of smoking cigarettes.

Comment: I love that we essentially gave the same exact response.

Comment: Can "the operation" be used of "surgery"?

Comment: I think you mean “instead of surgery,” and yes it can. :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is **John is two weeks out of surgery.** You can also simply say **John had the surgery *two weeks ago.***

- **Two weeks *away from* surgery** implies that he will have surgery in two weeks’ time.
- **Two weeks *from/off* surgery** don’t work, either. To say someone is *two weeks off* something generally means that for two weeks, they have not been indulging in that thing:

*I’m two weeks **off** dairy/video games/red meat/etc.* Something along these lines. Note though that this phrasing isn’t terribly common.